# How to create a dictionary in python from a set of values

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose we have a set of values

```
1.00
2.00
7.00
18.00
```

and now we want to create a dictionary such as

```
numbers = {'number': 1.00, 'number': 2.00, 'number': 3.00, 'number': 18.00}
```

how can we implement this in python

Comment: with duplicate keys????????

Comment: Python dictionaries must have unique keys, and Python does not use `var` either.

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by `var dict`? Did you came from JavaScript? After all, this is *not* valid Python syntax, and `dict` is a builtin `type()`, so you should**n't** use it as a normal symbol name... And duplicate keys? That's nonsense...

Comment: sorry about var removed it now.. yes I come from JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, you cannot create a dictionary like that.
It is not allowed (and not usable) to have duplicate keys.

What is possible is something like this:

```
var = { 'numbers': [1.00, 2.00, 3.00, 18.00] }
```

Which you can just do by looping over the values, adding them to an array and finally adding that to the dictionary like:

```
ndict = dict()
numbers = []
numbers.append(1.00)
numbers.append(2.00)
numbers.append(3.00)
numbers.append(18.00)
ndict['numbers'] = numbers
```

Comment: Eh... `var dict` again?

Comment: Haha sorry.. thank you for noticing. (copy paste error)